# How can i extend my Persistence Context into the Web-Module with Hibernate and JSF

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, jboss, icefaces

I'm working on a web application with ejb3 and jsf. I want to manipulate jpa entities in my jsf managed beans. Normaly when i use my entities in my managed beans i get LazyInitializationExceptions because the get detached when they enter the web container.

Is there a best practice how to solve this problem?

I know i can use the OpenSessionInView Pattern so i have an open hibernate session in JSF. Does that mean i can simply use myEntitiy.setSomething(...) and it will be persisted to the database?

Greetings,
Laures

Answer (score 1):

When using OpenSessionInView; calling "myEntitiy.setSomething(...)" will only change the value within that session. You must still persist the object when you want it be to stored for later use.

I prefer creating a "buisiness layer" where transactions start and within that business layer handle all jpa operations. That is, every business method is within its own transaction and provides a specified service for the gui layer above.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to see Seam, you can find it [here](http://seamframework.org/).

One of the biggest reasons why I switch to seam was this.